# Help with ambiguous syntax tree

Tags: ambiguity, syntactic-analysis

I have to do syntax trees for the two interpretations of this ambiguous sentence:

"The poor child's story is sad"

According to what I was told, one interpretation refers to the child and the other to the story but the problem is that I really can't see how to do these trees.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you don't get a good answer here I'd suggest you try the [linguists' stack exchange](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @SConroy doing parse trees is off topic on Linguistics.SE. Dispelling ambiguity might be on-topic here.

Comment: @Mitch. Ah, ok. Thanks for info.

Comment: As a parse tree, 'is sad' can only be a VP (or predicate), and the NP 'the poor child's story' is the subject. So parse-wise there is only one parse. Semantically however... whether the story is sad or ... no I don't see how anything is ambiguous here. The story is sad. It says nothing about whether the child is happy or sad. You'd expect the child to also be a bit sad, but maybe the child is an optimist?

Comment: The ambiguity could be whether it is the child that is poor or the child's story. It seems unlikely that anyone would describe a poor story as sad, but if it's just an exercise...

Comment: @Minty Ohhh... yeah, it is ambiguous. But a 'poor story' is not a natural way of saying the story is not very good. Anyway, there are two very simple trees, one leaning left, the other right: ((poor child's) story) = the story about the poor child, or  (poor (child's story)) = the child's story that is not very good.

Answer (score 3):

I can't really tell you how to draw your graphs, because there are many different drawing and labeling conventions. A minimalist graph looks quite different from a classical transformationalist graph, and neither will look at all like a dependency or a traditionalist Reed-Kellogg graph.

What I can do is point out the major components of the sentence, which you can adapt to your specific needs.

The basic Subject/Predicate structure of your sentence is not ambiguous: the Subject is realized by the determinate noun phrase *The poor child's story* and the Predicate is realized by the verb phrase *is sad*. The VP consists of a copula realized as the verb *is* and its complement realized as the adjective *sad*.

The ambiguities arise in your parse of the Subject:

- What's the function of the possessive? Is it a **determinative**, as in *John's hat*, or a **modifier**, as in *men's clothing*? That is, is this story one about or told by a particular child, or a story intended for children-in-general?
- What does *poor* modify? Is this a story about or told by a particular **poor child**, or one intended for **poor children**; or is it a **badly told** story for children-in-general, contrasted with one or more well-told stories?
- By the same token, which noun phrase does *The* determine -- the one headed by *child*, or the one headed by *story*?

Each of these choices will give you a different structure for the noun phrase, which you can represent according to whatever conventions you are called upon to use.

Comment: +1 for the list of different graphs. I like the distinction between childrens stories and children's stories (aimed at v written by) that one modern apostrophe convention gives.